# how to make changes in OROCRM

Tags: php, symfony, nav, orocrm

I am new to ORO platform. I know about theoritical part that it is based on symfony2 framework. Before this I did not use any framework of PHP. Now I want to know how to make changes in a UI of OROCRM like adding or deleting nav elements, adding form and so on. I searched everywhere but did not find anything worth. Can someone please help to get through this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seems some answers/examples can be found for example [here](https://www.orocrm.com/documentation/index/current/cookbook/how-to-create-and-customize-application-menu) or [here](https://github.com/orocrm/platform/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/NavigationBundle/README.md) for navigations.

Also, other documentations can be found [here](https://www.orocrm.com/documentation/index/current/cookbook)

Hope this helps you:)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Hi Nikita Makarov, My Magento Version 1.9.2.3, i have installed Bitnami OroCRM in Windows. After successfully installed then i going to Sync. The Sync is not complete i am getting an error like, Jobs Failed  1) oro_integration:sync_integration:1  2)  orocrm_magento:sync_initial_integration:1  3)  orocrm_magento:sync_initial_integration:1  4) oro_integration:sync_integration:1  5) orocrm_magento:sync_initial_integration:1 all the Jobs Failed. My status error : https://justpaste.it/4rkcs  and log error : https://justpaste.it/61uta How can i solve the issue?

Comment: Hi @gem

Sorry for the delay.

I assume that your question should be asked at [orocommunity slack channel](https://orocommunity.slack.com/) because I'm not strong in ORO's Magento Integration.
Or you may use another way to get community support, please see [ORO Community Docs](https://oroinc.com/orocrm/doc/2.0/community)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response.